# When does NYC East River Ferry depart 34th st

Tags: public-transport, new-york-city, ferries

I am planning to take the first East river ferry departing from East 34th street pier, on a Saturday.

On [this schedule](https://www.ferry.nyc/routes-and-schedules/route/east-river/), all it says is that the first ferry to arrive at the e34st pier is at 6:58am. Can I assume that this means that the first ferry to depart this location will be within ten minutes of this first arriving ferry?

In addition, does the ferry loop or backtrack?

So does it go from stop A>B>C>D>C>B>A or A>B>C>D>A>B>C>D?

My plan is to get on the ferry at e34st and get off at Dumbo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the schedule you linked, there are two buttons that say "LEAVING / RETURNING".  If you click the RETURNING button, you will see departure times from East 34th St.  The first departure on weekends is at 6:30 AM.

There is also a route map showing clearly that it backtracks: from Wall Street to Brooklyn to Midtown, then back to Brooklyn and then Wall Street.